# Как изменить цвет текста кнопки при нажатии?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Пробовал

```
self.bn01.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.bn01.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Не сработали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте документацию по следующим методам:

```
 - (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
 - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
 - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.bn01 setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```